# WIN10 | Configure printer properties using code

Tags: api, printing, preferences, zebra-printers

I am on the look for a solution to print with correct printer configurations with Windows 10 and a Zebra printer connected. To properly use the printer I need to define a group of properties to print in the correct format. Since I cannot be sure that the latest printing preference were saved, I'd like to use code to define all these printer properties. They include Page setup, Edit Stock and more options that can be configurable in the Printing Preferences of the printer instance in Windows.

Please help me in finding information on how to configure all these printer properties using code, preferably C#.
Thanks in advance,

Nadav

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To configure Zebra printers via an application, please first take a look at [the Link-OS Multiplatform SDK](https://www.zebra.com/us/en/products/software/barcode-printers/link-os/link-os-sdk.html), which has the libraries and API for C#. With this SDK, you can create a C# app that can communicates with the printer either via USB or TCP. The SDK has a class called SGD (Set-Get-Do), which provides API for the application to send the configuration commands to the printers.

The SGD can configure almost anything on the printer. You can refer to [the SGD section of this ZPL Programming Guide](https://www.zebra.com/content/dam/zebra_new_ia/en-us/manuals/printers/common/programming/zpl-zbi2-pm-en.pdf#page=567) for the detail of a specific SGD command.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer, it got me going, but developing came to a halt quite quickly. 
Trying to read the settings from a connected printer I used: 
ZebraPrinter genericPrinter = ZebraPrinterFactory.GetInstance(c);
ZebraPrinterLinkOs linkOsPrinter = ZebraPrinterFactory.CreateLinkOsPrinter(genericPrinter);
Where the CreateLinkOsPrinter command constantly returns null, even though the genericPrinter does identify my printer. 
Please guide me through this,
Thank you!

Comment: What's the printer model your computer connects with? Not all Zebra printers are Link-OS printers. You need to make sure the printer is a Link-OS printer.

Comment: It is a ZD220 printer.

Comment: ZD220 is a Link-OS Basic printer, i.e. not a full Link-OS printer. Please just treat it as a generic printer with the SDK.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I could not find any information on how to get/set settings for a generic printer. Please advise.

Comment: After you get a connection, call the methods in [SGD class](https://techdocs.zebra.com/link-os/2-14/pc_net/content/html/b52ae4f9-2e0d-ddb3-a853-927376bcada3.htm) to do the Set/Get/Do.

Comment: Thanks, I tried a simple command,

SGD.SET("ezpl.print_method","thermal trans", C);

printMethod = SGD.GET("ezpl.print_method", C);

Console.WriteLine($"SGD ezpl.print_method is {output}");

Prints:
ezpl.print_method is direct thermal

Why does the set function not work?
Thx!

Comment: ZD220 is a direct thermal printer only. You cannot change the print method to thermal transfer on ZD220, because it's not capable of doing thermal transfer. That's why the ezpl.print_method is unchangeable on ZD220.

Comment: Thanks, understood. In my application, after setting some parameter, get indeed shows the change. But after reopening the application, getting the same parameter shows the original default value. It seems that the setting is never saved to the printer itself. Most importantly, the change is never seen on the Windows printer properties. Please advise.

Comment: Please note that some of the settings on the printer cannot survive a power cycle or a reset, i.e. the settings go back to its default after a power cycle or a reset. Check the specific attribute you want to change is survivable or not. If the GET returns the new value right after the SET, then it means the new value was received by the printer successfully via the SET. If the GET returns the default value after a while, it could be either the value was changed unintentionally, or the printer went through a power cycle or a reset.

Comment: Even if it does reset on power loss, the most important feature (that the change will be seen on the windows printer properties) does not work. Please elaborate on this. Thank you

Comment: Can you provide the detail on the attributes that are not persisted on the printer, such as the names of the attributes used on SGD commands?